# How to merge multiple datasets by common variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have multiple datasets. Each of them has different number of attributes. I want to merge them all by common variable. This is 'union' if I use proc SQL. But there is hunderds of variables.
Example.

```
Dataset_Name    Number of columns   
dataset1           110
dataset2           120
dataset3           130
...                ...
```

Say they have 100 columns in common. The final dataset which contains all dataset1,dataset2,dataset3..etc
only has common columns(in this case, 100 columns).

How do I do this?

And how do I get columns for each dataset this is not in common with the final dataset. 
example: dataset1 will have 10 columns that are not in the final dataset, and list the name of 10 columns.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

UNION in SQL is equivalent to sequential SET in SAS.

```
data want;
set dataset1 dataset2 dataset3;
run;
```

Now, SAS by default includes all columns present in *any* dataset.  To limit to just what's in all datasets, you have to use a `keep` statement.

You can determine this using `proc sql`, among other ways.

```
proc sql;
select name into :commonlist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns C, dictionary.columns D
  where C.libname=D.libname
  and C.memname='DATASET1'
  and D.memname='DATASET2'
  and C.name=D.name
;
quit;
```

For more than two datasets it's more complicated and partially depends on your, but if you're comfortable in SQL you can figure that out pretty easily.  A similar construct can create a list of just dataset 1 variables.  The important part is the `into :commonlist separated by ' '`, which says to pull the select results into a macro variable called `commonlist`, separating rows by space.  (The colon says to create a macro variable, not a table.)

So you can then run:

```
data want (keep=&commonlist.) dset1(keep=&dset1list.) dset2(keep=&dset2list.);
  set dataset1(in=ds1) dataset2(in=ds2) dataset3(in=ds3);
  output want;
  if ds1 then output dset1;
  else if ds2 then output dset2;
  else if ds3 then output dset3;
run;
```

The `in=xyz` indicates which dataset a row came from.  Each output dataset can have a separate list of variables to keep.  You might want to keep the ID variable in those other datasets as well.

I will say that usually in SAS you don't do what you're doing here: it's not easy to do because it doesn't tend to be the best way to handle things - specifically, the little split off datasets.  In general you would just keep those extra variables on the master dataset, and they'd just be nulls for anyone not in a dataset with that variable - assuming it makes sense to make this 'master' dataset at all.